# Symfony 1.4 i18n helper in action

Tags: internationalization, symfony-1.4

I have problem with using I18n _*() in Symfony 1.4 action.
In component where I call _*('test',null,'translation') I get 'abcd' but when I call it in action I get 'test'. This indicate that it is not the problem with xliff file.

In settings.yml there is i18n on

```
all:
  .actions:
    error_404_module:       errors   # To be called when a 404 error is raised
    error_404_action:       error404  # Or when the requested URL doesn't match any route
#
    login_module:           default   # To be called when a non-authenticated user
    login_action:           login     # Tries to access a secure page
#
    secure_module:          default   # To be called when a user doesn't have
    secure_action:          secure    # The credentials required for an action
#
#    module_disabled_module: default   # To be called when a user requests 
#    module_disabled_action: disabled  # A module disabled in the module.yml
#
  .settings:

     i18n:                   on
```

The problem not even resolve adding to the action
sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers(array('I18N'));

Comment: Why translating in the action? You should translate strings in the view layer (call the helper function in your templates).

Comment: I don't have action template because I call action by ajax and return json

Comment: I have noticed that the problem only occurred when I want to call action in ajax query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$this->getContext()->getI18N()->__($text, $args, 'translation');
```

Comment: I use this statement all the time but I forget write it above.